Keycloak admin API. Method not allowed for put user profile
I'm trying to execute some requests to the Keycloak Admin API Rest to perform some operations.
I need to add a new attribute to the realm user profile. In the documentation: Keycloak Admin REST API this endpoint is provided: PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/profile in which according to the brief description the objective is to set the configuration for the user profile. In the body of the request I have included the default configuration, and also a new attribute.
When making this request:
### Add phone to user profile
PUT {{baseUrl}}/admin/reamls/{{realm}}/users/profile
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "UPConfig": {
        "attributes": [
         {
            "name": "username",
            "displayName": "${username}",
            "validations": {
                "length": {
                    "min": 3,
                    "max": 255
                },
                "username-prohibited-characters": {},
                "up-username-not-idn-homograph": {}
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": ["admin", "user"],
                "edit": ["admin", "user"]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "email",
            "displayName": "${email}",
            "validations": {
                "email": {},
                "length": {
                    "max": 255
                }
            },
            "required": {
                "roles": ["user"]
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": ["admin", "user"],
                "edit": ["admin", "user"]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "firstName",
            "displayName": "${firstName}",
            "validations": {
                "length": {
                    "max": 255
                },
                "person-name-prohibited-characters": {}
            },
            "required": {
                "roles": ["user"]
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": ["admin", "user"],
                "edit": ["admin", "user"]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "lastName",
            "displayName": "${lastName}",
            "validations": {
                "length": {
                    "max": 255
                },
                "person-name-prohibited-characters": {}
            },
            "required": {
                "roles": ["user"]
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": ["admin", "user"],
                "edit": ["admin", "user"]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "phone",
            "displayName": "User phone",
            "required": {
                "roles": ["user"]
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": ["admin", "user"],
                "edit": ["admin", "user"]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        }],
        "groups": [
        {
            "name": "user-metadata",
            "displayHeader": "User metadata",
            "displayDescription": "Attributes, which refer to user metadata"
        }]
    }
}

I am getting:
{
  "error": "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed",
  "error_description": "For more on this error consult the server log at the debug level."
}

What could I be doing wrong?

Did you enabled the profile feature?

You don't need "UPConfig" in your JSON payload.
Set Profile Endpoint
PUT http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/{realm}/users/profile

With Bearer master token
payload
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "username",
            "displayName": "${username}",
            "validations": {
                "length": {
                    "min": 3,
                    "max": 255
                },
                "username-prohibited-characters": {},
                "up-username-not-idn-homograph": {}
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ],
                "edit": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "email",
            "displayName": "${email}",
            "validations": {
                "email": {},
                "length": {
                    "max": 255
                }
            },
            "required": {
                "roles": [
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ],
                "edit": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "firstName",
            "displayName": "${firstName}",
            "validations": {
                "length": {
                    "max": 255
                },
                "person-name-prohibited-characters": {}
            },
            "required": {
                "roles": [
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ],
                "edit": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "lastName",
            "displayName": "${lastName}",
            "validations": {
                "length": {
                    "max": 255
                },
                "person-name-prohibited-characters": {}
            },
            "required": {
                "roles": [
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ],
                "edit": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "multivalued": false
        },
        {
            "name": "phone",
            "displayName": "User phone",
            "validations": {},
            "annotations": {},
            "required": {
                "roles": [
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "permissions": {
                "view": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ],
                "edit": [
                    "admin",
                    "user"
                ]
            },
            "group": "user-metadata",
            "multivalued": false
        }
    ],
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "user-metadata",
            "displayHeader": "User metadata",
            "displayDescription": "Attributes, which refer to user metadata"
        }
    ]
}

demo.py
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID
import requests
import json

class KeycloakService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.keycloak_url = 'http://localhost:8080'

    def get_token_user(self, realm, client_id, username, password):
        try:
            keycloak_openid_user = KeycloakOpenID(server_url=self.keycloak_url,
                                                   realm_name=realm,
                                                   client_id=client_id)
            
            # Uses keycloak_openid_user instance
            token = keycloak_openid_user.token(username, password)
            return token['access_token']
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error obtaining user token: {e}")
            return None

    def get_user_profile(self, token, realm):
        try:
            headers = {
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
            }
            # Keycloak user profile endpoint
            url = f"{self.keycloak_url}/admin/realms/{realm}/users/profile"
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            response.raise_for_status()
            
            # Print the JSON response of the user profile
            profile_json = response.json()
            print("User Profile JSON:", json.dumps(profile_json, indent=4))
            return profile_json
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error fetching user profile: {e}")
            return None
        
    def set_user_profile(self, token, realm, profile):
        try:
            headers = {
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            # URL to update the Keycloak user profile
            url = f"{self.keycloak_url}/admin/realms/{realm}/users/profile"
            response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(profile))
            response.raise_for_status()
            print("User profile updated successfully.")
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error updating user profile: {e}")        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keycloak_service = KeycloakService()
    
    # Obtain master token
    realm = 'master'
    client_id = 'admin-cli'
    username = 'admin'
    password = 'admin'
    master_token = keycloak_service.get_token_user(realm, client_id, username, password)
    if master_token:
        print("Master token:", master_token)
        realm = 'my-realm'
        profile = keycloak_service.get_user_profile(master_token, realm)
        # Add new "phone" attribute to the profile
        if profile and 'attributes' in profile:
            phone_attribute = {
                "name": "phone",
                "displayName": "User phone",
                "validations": {},
                "annotations": {},
                "required": {
                    "roles": ["user"]
                },
                "permissions": {
                    "view": ["admin", "user"],
                    "edit": ["admin", "user"]
                },
                "group": "user-metadata",
                "multivalued": False
            }
            profile['attributes'].append(phone_attribute)
            
            # Update the user profile with the new attribute
            keycloak_service.set_user_profile(master_token, realm, profile)
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain user token")

You need to install dependencies
pip install requests python-keycloak

Before add phone profile

Run demo.py

After add phone profile

